# asp.net Login Username is Blank

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I am just starting with asp.net and have run into an issue I cannot resolve. I have looked at a number of similar issues but none of the responses have fixed this.

I am using the Login control from the Toolbox and it built the following aspx:

```
 <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFBD6" BorderColor="#FFDFAD" BorderPadding="4" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CreateUserText="Register" CreateUserUrl="~/Registration.aspx" DestinationPageUrl="~/ClientInfo.aspx" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#333333" TextLayout="TextOnTop">
        <InstructionTextStyle Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Black" />
        <LoginButtonStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#990000" />
        <TextBoxStyle Font-Size="0.8em" />
        <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="0.9em" ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:Login>
```

The DestinationURL is set to my next page, ClientInfo. On that page I use the LoginName control:

```
 <span class="usernme"><asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" FormatString="Welcome, {0}" />
```

This is always empty. I tried to see if anything was there by putting this in the code behind for the ClientInfo form:

```
If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
        lblSelected.Text = User.Identity.Name
    Else
        lblSelected.Text = "No user identity available."
    End If
```

It hit the Else, so IsAuthenticated not True.

When I login it does stop an unregistered ID. When I login with my registered ID it redirects to the ClientInfo form, as I expect.

Here is the web.config entry I have for the authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <!--<forms name="asp.ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" protection="All" /> -->
  <forms name="clients" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" timeout="20" protection="All" path="/"/>
</authentication>
```

I am sure this is a simple mistake but...I am a bit lost.

Any help appreciated!